# Electric potential of an arbitrary resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, boundary-conditions

**General case:** Suppose that we have a resistor which is made from material with conductivity $\sigma$. We set the voltage at the ends:
[image]
I think according to the Laplace equation we have:
$$\nabla^2V = 0$$ With boundary conditions:  $$ \text{Portions that touch the right plate:} \ \ \ V = 0 \\ \text{Portions that touch the left plate:} \ \ \ V = V_0 \\ \text{The surrounding space is nonconducting} \implies \text{Other portions:} \ \ \  \mathbf{J}.\mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0\implies \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0\implies \frac{\partial V}{\partial n} = 0$$
Where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit vector normal to the surface at each point. Is this correct?

**Special case:** In Griffiths "introduction to electrodynamics", there is a somewhat similar problem:
[image]
He mentions that the shape of the cross section is irrelevant but it should be the same across the resistor. So why this assumption is necessary? Also is it necessary that cross sections be perpendicular to the $z$-axis? Maybe these two assumptions are just required to make sure $V(z) = \frac{V_0z}{L}$ works. If that's the case, I think we don't need the first assumption(i.e. the cross section stays constant across the length).

**Edit:** So is the formulation of the problem correct in the general case? If it's correct, can we drop the constant cross section assumption? I mean in that case we have $$\nabla^2V = 0$$ With boundary conditions:  $$ \text{Right cross section:} \ \ \ V = 0 \\ \text{Left cross section:} \ \ \ V = V_0 \\ \text{Other portions of the surface:} \ \ \ \frac{\partial V}{\partial n} = 0$$
I think also in this case $V(z) = \frac{V_0z}{L}$ solves the Laplace equation and by the uniqueness theorem, it's the only solution.

Comment: Define $\mathbf n$.

Comment: @my2cts My mean is the unit vector normal to the surface at each point.

Comment: Please clarify  Are you saying there is no current between the plates?

Comment: @my2cts I'm saying that $\mathbf{J}.\mathbf{\hat{n}}=0$ for the portions of the surface of resistor which don't have contact with plates since the surrounding space is nonconducting.

Answer (score 1):

> He mentions that the shape of the cross section is irrelevant but it should be the same across the resistor. So why [is this assumption] necessary? Also is it necessary that cross sections be perpendicular to the z-axis?

These assumptions are necessary to simplify the problem so that the field lines are straight (so that a simple relationship between conductivity and resistance can be applied) and so that calculus isn't required in the solution.

For field lines perpendicular to the cut surfaces of an infinitesimal vertical sliver of this resistor (of length $dl$) with cross-sectional area $A$, the resistance is $dR=dl/(\sigma A$). The total resistance—as long as the cross-sectional shape is constant—is then just $R=L/(\sigma A)$. If the cross-sectional area were to vary slightly moving down the resistor (as a function of the distance $l$, or $A(l)$), the resistance would be given by $$R=\int_0^L\frac{dl}{\sigma A(l)},$$ which is harder that the constant-shape calculation. In addition, we would expect [some degree of additional resistance from the field lines changing shape](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/6-expert-advice-on-power-integrity/post/534-the-perils-of-right-angle-turns-at-dc); this effect might be negligible in practice for slight shape variations, but Griffith wants to ensure that you don't have to think about it.

Edit: Another reason to specify a constant cross-sectional shape is to ensure that $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ has no $z$-direction component. If it did have a $z$-direction component, then $V(z)=\frac{V_0z}{L}$ could not be a solution because it would not always satisfy $\mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}=0$. This is related to the discussion of straight field lines above.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand your answer using the Laplace equation and its boundary conditions, please? My main problem here is about using the Laplace equation to solve the question.

Comment: The Laplace equation simply says that there are no voltage sinks or sources inside the resistor (otherwise the divergence would be nonzero). That's a separate issue.

Comment: If the question is different from the one I answered, please edit your question to express the key question clearly.

Comment: I clarified the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you; I edited my answer.

Comment: Could you explain why varying cross section implies that $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ has $z$-direction component, please?

Comment: Try drawing a resistor with a varying cross section. Then add the associated normal vectors. Every example I draw has at least some surface normals with at least some z-direction contribution. What do you find?